# Sells falling down after Clear Cache - Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, cache

Before doing a Clear Cache Magento, I got about **3-4 sells per day**, after doing a Clear Cache Magento, the sells gone to ZERO.

What's going on?

This is not the first time that I got this issue with Magento (1.9.2.1).

Answer (score 0):

In Magento 1.9.2.1, clearing the cache is something that you should do when you need to see changes that you made to the back end of the system (such as pricing updates, CMS content changes, new images, etc) and allow them to show up on the front end of the site.

Without actually seeing the site, two things could be happening when you clear the cache:
1. Your site could be a lot slower, as it's trying to now rebuild the cache and this can take time.  If this is a full page cache extension, like Amasty FPC, then a site visitor has to visit that page for it to be created in the cached folder.

2. Second, it could be that when you clear the cache, the site is breaking or some functionality is not working like it did before.  If this is the case (or just to make sure), I would recommend doing a full test on the site, including placing an order through the system.

It also could be a seasonal change, or a change in your search rankings.  One more thing to check: make sure that your site is okay to be indexed by search engines.  This is a tag on the home page and other pages of the site (index, follow) as well as also specified in the robots.txt file on your site root.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Jeff, however: Each time I change contents I use the related cache element (Like Output HTML), but I never use the "Clear Cache Magento" Red Button... 1. I don't know if I use full page cache extension (I'm not using Amasty FPC), but really, the Server spends about 2 mins to clear the cache. Maybe this extension can help me in this case? Is it normal that, in order to get a sell I need **to wait about a week after this action**?... 2. After clear cache, I've tried to place an order and all things works well... Really, can you explain me about tags like index,follow?